# Splitting a string gives different result when saved to variable and when console.log-ing it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a really simple function that is executed when the `$location` changes (see below).
The problem is, the occurrence of `$location.path().split("/")` in the assignment returns `["browser"]`, when `$location.path() == "/browser"`, but running it directly inside the `console.log` returns `["", "browser"]`. how can this difference be explained reasonably?

```
angular.module("blah", [])
.controller("navigation", function($scope, $location) {
    var updatePage = function() {
        var temp = $location.path().split("/");
        console.log($location.path(), $location.path().split("/"), temp);
        $scope.page = temp.splice(0,1)[0];
        $scope.args = temp;
        //console.log($scope.page);
    };
    $scope.changePage = function(path) {
        if (path.match("^https?:")) {
            window.location = path;
        } else {
            $location.path(path);
        }
    };
    $scope.args = [];
    $scope.$on("$locationChangeSuccess", function(event, data) {
        updatePage();
    });
    updatePage();
});
```

Comment: both should end up with same solution as `["", "browser"]`.. seems odd. I tried whereas I am getting the same array, can you check what `$location.path()` holds exactly.

Comment: Is it because you have console.log($location.path().split("/"), temp); instead of just console.log(temp)?

Comment: @user2355891 even though it has be like `[array, array]` in console with same array.  if you want you can check it up like `var loca = "/bower".split("/"); console.log("/bower".split("/"), loca)`

Comment: @Praveen $location.path() is always returning "/browser".

Comment: unable to reproduce it,  can you make a fiddle with some static values?

Comment: It works fine for me (both methods produce `["", "browser"]`).

Comment: How very strange, can't reproduce the issue outside my code. Posted whole controller on question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably see the "issue" with a code like this:

```
var temp = $location.path().split("/");
$scope.page = temp.splice(0,1)[0];
...
console.log($location.path(), $location.path().split("/"), temp);
```

At the point of logging, `temp` has already been **[`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)d**. **[`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** (unlike **[`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)**) removed the elments from the original array as well.

---

**UPDATE:**

Another possible cause is this:
Firefox (unlike Chrome) does not log the **value** of the object at the time of logging, but a **reference** to the object (Arrays are objects as well). Thus, any later modification of the Array (e.g. splicing) will affect logged object/Array as well.

If you log `JSON.stringify(temp)` instead, you should see the expected results.

Comment: I don't see why the logging would be pushed under the assignment, that's really strange. As far as I know, Javascript is supposed to execute each statement sequentially, no? In my code, I log the variables /before/ splicing, but it still gives different results.

Comment: I ended up removing the leading slash from the string before splitting, and all was well again.

Comment: It is strange. For me logging before the splicing produces the expected results. This is very weird if it works otherwise for you (and I would be very surprised). It would be interesting if you could create a fiddle that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I still don't see the issue. How can I reproduce the problem ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I pasted the updated code. see again, the file scripts.js, and look at your console, then click the "Level Browser" link

Comment: I did, but I still see `["", "browser"] ["", "browser"]` (as expected). I am on Chrome.

Comment: Hm...Are you by any chance using Firefox ? Firefox logs a reference to the object (Arrays are objects as well of course). So, any later change to the Array (e.g. splicing) will reflect the logged instance as well. If you log `JSON.stringify(temp)` instead you should see the expected results.

Comment: Hmm, that must have been the case. Indeed logging the JSON representation does yield expected results.